# Rails: How to seperate jquery from html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Really simple question.

I'm writing a plugin for Redmine in Ruby on Rails.

I want to do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xp73Q/3/)

I have this in my form.html.rb:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td >Specific operations/procedures</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" value="mfi_nam9" class="checkme"/>Other(please specify)<br/>
            <input type="text" name="mfi_nam9" disabled="true" >
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >General principles/strategies</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" value="mfi_nam8" class="checkme"/>Other(please specify):<br/>
            <input type="text" name="mfi_nam8" disabled="true">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

# compatibility for use as redmine plugin
<% content_for :header_tags do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'checkbox_enable', :plugin => 'students' %>
<% end %>
```

I have this in my "checkbox_enable.js" file:

```
$(function() {
  $('.checkme').attr('checked', true);
  $('.checkme').click(function(){
    if($('input[name='+ $(this).attr('value')+']').attr('disabled') == false){
      $('input[name='+ $(this).attr('value')+']').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('input[name='+ $(this).attr('value')+']').attr('disabled', false);
    }
  });
}
```

Look at my very first line of that file. I don't know if it's right. I don't really understand the difference between javascript and jquery that well. But the javascript has no impact on the html file.

How do I make this work?

EDIT:

I just noticed that the fiddle only works for jquery 1.5. Or it seems that way. Does that mean there's a good chance of it just not working on a lot (most?) browsers? If so, why would anyone use jquery for anything?

Comment: Did you add a script link to the js file? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Give the following a try.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.checkme').click(function(){
        // is this checkbox checked
        // ~~~~~
        var bChecked = $(this).is(':checked');

        // enable/disable text box based on the checkbox value
        // ~~~~~
        $('input[name='+ $(this).attr('value')+']').attr('disabled', !bChecked);
    });

    // trigger click event on page ready
    // OR you could remove this line and change the defaults in your 
    // table definition to have the checkboxes checked and the inputs enabled
    // by default!
    // ~~~~~
    $('.checkme').click();
});
```